# execution time on git-bash

Tags: node.js, git, bash, socket.io, git-bash

I am using git Bash to create a socket.io project with Nodejs on Windows 10. The terminal is comparatively slow on execution.

`$ npm init` works after 10 seconds.

After generating the package.json, the following is displayed

```
is it ok? (yes)
```

I accept by the return key and it blinks the cursor for like ever ?

Is it my OS or something else ?

Comment: iirc npm on windows is a batch script, have you tried the command on a regular command prompt?

Comment: thanks, I will right away